# Workout t-shirts and types of fabric

Tags: clothing

I have been working out in the same t-shirts I normally use, recognised that's a mistake, the washing machine dont remove the odors completely, still some left after rinsing once with vinegar.

What should i look for in workout t-shirts and fabrics? I do bodyweight training, running and some machines at a gym.
Merino wool, cotton, bamboo, synthetics? 
Whatever they sell in a sports store? 
Cheap cottonshirts from clothing stores?

Comment: Primarily opinion-based for sure, my recommendation is to get a moisture-wicking t-shirt to solve your particular problem.